# Return process id

Tags: windows, process, pid

I have this issue that I want to resolve. Lets think we have this situation. We have one instance of notepad.exe running. I run another notepad.exe. Now I want to kill the latter. How can I do it?

If I was able to know the pid of last notepad.exe then I could kill it. But how to get the PID of last opened program?

Another way is to give every application a unique image name. From what I learned it seems impossible becouse image names are hard coded into the binary file.

So any ideas?

P.S. As you already noticed this is all in windows.

Comment: are you in control of starting the notepad process?

Comment: Yes, I am. I am writing a program in C++ that keeps track of running processes and if any of these crash of freeze, that program kills (if needed) and restarts them. All these watched programs have the same image names.

Comment: But if you start them yourself and you use CreateProcess then you already know the PID from the dwProcessId field...?

Comment: I start it using system() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are someone else's processes (i.e. you didn't start them yourself), then Windows keeps track of [when the process was started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.starttime.aspx) (or its "[creation time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372(VS.85).aspx)"), so I expect you could just find whichever process started last using that information.

Answer (score 0):

Well, how are you launching the process? For example, if you are launching it from C#, the static `Process.Start` method returns a `Process` instance, which has an `Id`, and a `Kill()` method. The mechanism will differ between architectures/languages...

And if you aren't doing it through code, it may be off-topic ;-p